# Turn on torch/flashlight and camera at the same time on iPhone X

Tags: ios, avfoundation, iphone-x

Is there a way to keep the flashlight on while `AVCaptureSession` is running on video mode on the iPhone X?

I have Swift 4 code that turns on the flashlight then starts getting video frames from the camera. I know it works for iPhone 4,5 and 6. But with an iPhone X the flashlight does not come on when I start the capture session.

```
session = AVCaptureSession()
if self.session.canSetSessionPreset(AVCaptureSession.Preset.inputPriority) {
    self.session.sessionPreset = .inputPriority
}
//This is the wide angle camera device
camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
//I could also use telephoto, same problem
//camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInTelephotoCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)
if camera == nil {
    return
}
if self.camera.isTorchModeSupported(.on) {
    camera.activeFormat = selectBestFormat(camera.formats)
    camera.torchMode = .on
    try? camera.setTorchModeOn(level: 1.0)
    camera.unlockForConfiguration()
}

let cameraInput = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.camera)


let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
let captureQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "captureQueue")
videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: captureQueue)
videoOutput.videoSettings = [
    (kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyObject) as! AnyHashable as! String : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
]

self.session.addInput(cameraInput)
self.session.addOutput(videoOutput)
//If I don't start the session the torch is on 
self.session.startRunning()
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491228/iphone-x-flashlight-turns-off-when-ar-camera-is-enabled) has the same problem. The problem in my case is that the flashlight turns off as soon as the `AVCaptureSession` starts.

I have tried turning the flashlight on after starting the session, I have tried a number of different camera configurations. I have also tried using the two different camera lenses. For all those configurations the light goes off.

If there is no solution, please let me know if there is a bug logged for this. Or I will log one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

had the same problem. Seems to be a bug in iOS 11/iPhone X

I found a workaround ... not very elegant, but works ;-)

```
    if let device = captureDevice {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.setTorchLevel(device: device, to: 0)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            self.setTorchLevel(device: device, to: 1)
        }
    }
```

Even on the iPhone the "Have you tried to turn it off and on again" works

Comment: It's not 100% perfect but it's fine for now.